# Losing data in Python 3.5 shutil.copyfile

Tags: python-3.x, shutil

I'm using shutil library. When I using :

```
backuped = shutil.copyfile(file1, file2)
```

`file2` is empty. There is not any problem with `shutil.move`. How can I copy file without losing data?

Answer (score 1):

Are you on Mac? Shutil does not work properly on Mac according to the PyScripter pop-up.

You also need to be more specific, I could not replicate this problem. However, I would suggest checking:

- File Extensions
- File Locations
- File Metadata (this is what's lost when copying on a Mac, also, with
  Mac, shutil.move DOES work, so it may be that)

You COULD do it manually with files as I'll show below, however I think this way is slower than other built-in methods.

```
with open (file1, "rb") as f1:
    with open (file2, "wb") as f2:
        f2.writelines(f1.readlines())
```

This created an exact copy of the file with the location `file1` to the location `file2`. This method works with all files and can be implemented with pickle to encrypt and serialise objects.

`file2` does not need to already be a file either.

Comment: OP. Is this what you were looking for? If not just explain what it is that you need and I'll try to sort it out for you (if I know how that is, I'm no fan of sophistry).